# Rails - is it possible to find the record that violates unique validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Considering following as an example

```
class SuperHero < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :weapon, uniqueness: true
end
```

So when I create

```
SuperHero.create!(name: "Thor", weapon: "hammer")
SuperHero.create!(name: "Spiderman", weapon: "hammer") => Weapon has already been taken
```

Is it possible to add, the error message `Weapon has already been taken by Thor` using the default unique validation? So that the user can easily find the whom currently the weapon is assigned to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to implement your own validation. Something like this:

```
class SuperHero < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :weapon, uniqueness: true

  before_validation -> {
    existing_super_hero = SuperHero.find_by_weapon self.weapon

    if existing_super_hero && existing_super_hero.id != self.id
      self.errors.add(:base, "Weapon has already been taken by #{existing_super_hero.name}")
      throw :abort
    end
  }
end
```